TV pilot about secret spy organization who could erase memories?
I remember seeing what I think was a pilot on Canadian (Ontario) TV back in the 70's or 80's. I believe it's American, and was definitely live-action. It was set in locations that were summer-weather like.
In it, a woman reporter is recruited into a secret spy organization by the male lead. The agency is accessed by an elevator where you insert a key and the control panel flips over to a second one. 
The agency is organized by colour-coded sections, and I think the Black one had the power to make anyone forget their experiences with them.
At the end of the movie/episode, the lead bumps into the woman just as the clock strikes the hour, and she suddenly forgets everything that has happened. Like Men In Black, but decades earlier!

I suggest you try - 'The Fifth Corner' (1992) - a promo for this on youtube mentions a spy and a female reporter. Also look at 'Masquerade' (TV Series 1983–1984) - An intelligence organization recruits civilian specialists for individual missions requiring their skills (13 episodes). I can't confirm the memory wipe plot point in this show, but 'The Fifth Corner' has the spy struggling to recall his past. Good luck.

Thanks Harry! This seemed close, and I checked out "Call to Danger" which was a one-off pilot attempt starring Peter Graves, but I don't think either is it. I particularly remember the secret agency being organized by colour-coded sections, and the ability to erase someone's recent memory, seemingly through the air! thanks though! Peter

Well, I'm now fixated on the idea of finding the show you have described here, so (as time permits) I will keep on digging. Can I ask you to put a comment here if you ever manage to track it down? I promise I'll do the same if I find anything. Cheers.

Absolutely Harry! Thanks a lot, I've tried periodically over the years, but it has eluded me every time...seems like a site admin didn't like my question for some reason, so I think they closed this item, but your message still got through. Thanks again!

I've been checking out some of those anthology shows - Ray Bradbury Theater, Night Gallery, etc. - in case that's where you saw it. So far no match though. Still digging....it's got to be out there! (I'm a believer).

Thanks Harry! I know I did see it, but it was so long ago...wish I could remember a star's name or two, but that's memory for you, maybe section black erased mine! Really appreciate it, Peter

Hi Peter. Still no luck I'm afraid, but I don't give up easily. I think they might be deleting these threads soon, so I've re-posted your search question (as scallywag) at: movieforums.com/community/showthread.php?t=52643

It would be great if somebody there recognizes your show. If I ever track it down, I'll put the answer there. Cheers


Thanks a lot Harry! This has certainly turned out to be an elusive memory to track down! Peter

That's quiet similar to Torchwood 2006 Pilot but the time frame doesn't match.
There were a male lead recruiting a female who were investigating them, they acsess their head quarter via an elevator and they were able to make people forget, which they did to her at some point.

During a murder investigation in Cardiff, Gwen Cooper spies on a mysterious group of five people calling themselves "Torchwood" led by Captain Jack Harkness. Another member, Suzie, uses a metal gauntlet to temporarily bring the victim to life in an attempt to identify his killer. Jack notes Gwen's presence, causing her to flee the scene. The next day, she runs into Jack again at a hospital and, following him, finds a sealed-off area where she runs into a Weevil, which kills a porter. Jack arrives, giving Gwen the opportunity to escape. As she leaves the hospital, she spots the Torchwood vehicle and follows it. She learns from her office that the vehicle is unregistered, and that while there was a "Jack Harkness" who disappeared in 1941,[1] there is not one currently on record. She follows the vehicle to Roald Dahl Plass, where she continues the pursuit on foot only to lose sight of them as they pass a large fountain. She then learns from her partner Andy that all personnel at the hospital have been accounted for.
Catching sight of a pizza delivery scooter, she inquires at the local pizza store and learns they make deliveries to Torchwood. Disguised as a pizza delivery girl, she enters a tourist centre where Ianto presses a button to reveal a secret passageway and lets her through. Following it, Gwen eventually finds herself in the Torchwood Hub, where the rest of the Torchwood team members initially try to ignore her entrance but break into fits of laughter, well aware of who she is. Jack shows Gwen around the Hub, including the captured Weevil from the hospital; they then leave the Hub via a pavement slab lift, which takes them to Roald Dahl Plass in front of the fountain. Jack explains that a perception filter exists around the spot they are standing, making them invisible to passersby, explaining why Gwen lost track of the team earlier. Jack takes Gwen to a pub, and over a drink, explains that the purpose of Torchwood is to help monitor and control the flotsam and jetsam of the time-space vortex that falls to Earth through the rift that exists on the site where the Hub was built. As Gwen wonders why Jack is telling her all of this, he explains that he has placed an amnesia pill in her drink, and that she will have forgotten the information by morning. Gwen races home and tries to type out a message to herself before the pill's effects are complete, but falls asleep; Ianto remotely turns off her computer, causing the message to be lost.
The next day at work, Gwen is shown a drawing of the knife believed to have been used on the victim two days prior, which triggers a series of memories. These solidify when she spots a Millennium Centre programme with the word "Remember" in her own handwriting at home, and she returns to the Plass. Suzie is waiting for her there, and explains that the effects of the amnesia pill could be broken with a specific image, in this case the knife. Suzie goes onto explain that it was she who killed the man Gwen saw resurrected, as well as other victims, in order to test the metal gauntlet, with the hope of learning to make its resurrection effect permanent. Suzie pulls a gun on Gwen; as she does, Jack rises from the pavement lift, and Suzie turns and shoots him in the head, killing him. To Suzie's surprise, Jack then recovers and his gunshot wound disappears. Jack tries to coax Suzie to stop, but she puts the gun to her chin and kills herself. Gwen falls to her knees, remembering everything.
In the Hub, the metal gauntlet is sealed away in a box labelled "NOT FOR USE", while Suzie's body is placed into their morgue. Standing on the roof of the Millennium Centre, Jack tells Gwen that he died once, but was brought back to life, and that he has been immortal ever since. He adds that he needs to find the right sort of doctor who can explain what happened. Jack goes on to explain that in the 21st century, "everything changes," and agrees with Gwen that perhaps Torchwood can do more to help people, and offers her a job, which she accepts.





Thanks very much...that's funny, as a life-long Dr.Who fan, I had seen the Torchwood premiere, but never made that connection. You're right, there are many similarities to what I described, but alas this isn't what I was asking about though, it was much earlier. I've scoured the net but never been able to track down what it was. Thanks for answering though!

No problem. I thought there might be a chance that you're way off about the time frame or mixing 2 shows up or something. Still I Hope someone can recognize what you're looking for.

Thanks Madmada!

That's an answer, you can comments to @Peter11 above (under his question). I agree though that those were a bit of harsh close votes.
